# Blender to Unity Vertex Color (Alpha) Data Doesn't Work

Tags: unity-game-engine, attributes, transparency, alpha, fbx

I know there are many threads on google like that, but I went through all of that and none seems to work. I try to do the disc, that has opacity on the edges and right in the middle with vertex colors but it looks like my vertex color data doesn't import into Unity properly.

What I do:

1. In blender I add mesh and add attribute "Color" - Face Corner & Byte Color
2. In vertex paint mode I paint on the model with "erase alpha" brush settings. The effect is not visible unless in shading mode I pin color attribute node alpha into base color - this way I can see the alpha being erased in material preview mode. I tried changing viewport shading (in solid mode) to attribute instead of default one, but that doesn't work. So based on that I assume that since I have my attribute added, and alpha erased I move to the export.
3. I go export - fbx (default settings). And yet when I import fbx, or .blend into Unity there is no data stored. I use shader that works with model I got from tutorial I was following - but on my model it doesn't.

Any ideas why could that be? I would attach link to my .fbx and .blend but I don't know how and it blocks wetransfer so let me know if I can somehow provide you with one. Thanks!